# Is it possible to cross-compile 64bit on 32bit machine a position-independent-executable?

Tags: c++, openssl, cross-compiling, executable, 32bit-64bit

I want to compile a 64bit position-independent-executable on a 32bit machine. The command-line I use does not work:

```
g++ code.cpp -lcrypto -Fpie -pie -m64 -o  executable
```

The 32bit compilation works fine with the -Fpie option and without the -Fpie option the 64bit compilation works fine aswell.

The error-message is:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccN2ciG5.o: Die Umlagerung von 
/tmp/ccN2ciG5.o: error adding symbols: Ungültiger Wert
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Delete all temporary files ala `make clean` and then does the error still occur?

Comment: as I understand 'make clean' it removes the executables I compiled using makefile created. I don't understand how this should help. How can I perform 'make clean'?

Comment: Probably `-lcrypto` for 64-bit on your machine is `.a` without PIE code

Comment: how can I check that?

Comment: Not an expert but you would probably need to install `64bit` versions of any libraries you use.

Comment: During configuring cross-compilation, I have set up all OpenSSL libraries (including libcrypto) for 64bit installation. So that should not be a problem, right?

Comment: @Maxi - the object files in `libcrypto.a` have to be built with `-fPIC`. `-fPIC` can be used for `-fPIE` executables, but the reverse is not true (`-fPIE` and `-pie` cannot be used for `-fPIC` and `-shared`). You should probably configure OpenSSL with the `shared` option to ensure `-fPIC`.